# Set contents of set in constructor

Tags: java, set

I have an Animal class...

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private AnimalType type;
    private String noun;
    private String scientificNoun;
    private short minSizeCm;
    private short maxSizeCm;
    private double minWeightGrams;
    private double maxWeightGrams;
    private Set<AnimalColour> animalColour = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<AnimalLocomotion> locomotion = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<AnimalCountry> country = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<AnimalNaturalHabitat> naturalHabitat = new HashSet<>();

    public Animal(AnimalType type, String noun, String scientificNoun, short minSizeCm, short maxSizeCm,
                  double minWeightGrams, double maxWeightGrams, Set<AnimalColour> animalColour,
                  Set<AnimalLocomotion> locomotion, Set<AnimalCountry> country,
                  Set<AnimalNaturalHabitat> naturalHabitat) {
        this.type = type;
        this.noun = noun;
        this.scientificNoun = scientificNoun;
        this.minSizeCm = minSizeCm;
        this.maxSizeCm = maxSizeCm;
        this.minWeightGrams = minWeightGrams;
        this.maxWeightGrams = maxWeightGrams;
        this.animalColour = animalColour;
        this.locomotion = locomotion;
        this.country = country;
        this.naturalHabitat = naturalHabitat;
    }
}
```

I also have a Bird class...

```
public abstract class Bird extends Animal {
    private BirdBeakShape beakShape;
    private Set<AnimalColour> featherColour;
    private short minWingspanLengthCm;
    private short maxWingspanLengthCm;

    public Bird(String noun, String scientificNoun, short minSizeCm, short maxSizeCm,
                double minWeightGrams, double maxWeightGrams, Set<AnimalColour> animalColour,
                Set<AnimalLocomotion> locomotion, Set<AnimalCountry> country,
                Set<AnimalNaturalHabitat> naturalHabitat, BirdBeakShape beakShape, Set<AnimalColour> featherColour,
                short minWingspanLengthCm, short maxWingspanLengthCm) {
        super(AnimalType.BIRD, noun, scientificNoun, minSizeCm, maxSizeCm, minWeightGrams, maxWeightGrams, animalColour,
                locomotion, country, naturalHabitat);
        this.beakShape = beakShape;
        this.featherColour = featherColour;
        this.minWingspanLengthCm = minWingspanLengthCm;
        this.maxWingspanLengthCm = maxWingspanLengthCm;
    }
}
```

And a `Buzzard` class...

```
import java.util.Set;

public class Buzzard extends Bird {
    public Buzzard(String noun, String scientificNoun, short minSizeCm, short maxSizeCm,
                   double minWeightGrams, double maxWeightGrams, Set<AnimalColour> animalColour,
                   Set<AnimalLocomotion> locomotion, Set<AnimalCountry> country,
                   Set<AnimalNaturalHabitat> naturalHabitat, BirdBeakShape beakShape, Set<AnimalColour> featherColour,
                   short minWingspanLengthCm, short maxWingspanLengthCm) {
        super("Buzzard", "Buteo buteo", (short) 51, (short) 57, 550, 1300,
                AnimalColour.BROWN);
    }
}
```

I am trying to set the different colours of Buzzard in the constructor. Like brown, black, grey. The colour enum is...

```
public enum AnimalColour {
    BROWN,
    BLACK,
    WHITE,
    GREY,
    GREY_BROWN,
    BLACK_STREAKS,
    GREEN,
    CREAM
}
```

However, I do not know how to set various colours from the enum as a set in the constructor (or any better way of doing it appreciated). Also, there is so much duplication. Is there any way to reduce that? Because I will eventually also have mammal and reptile class, so even now there's too much code repeated

Comment: Putting things,  be they `enum`s, `String`s, `Widget`s or whatever,  into a `Set` is done the same way everywhere, be it in a constructor or an ordinary method.

Comment: Guessing you didn't do _only_ `animalColour.add(AnimalColour.Brown, AnimalColour.Black), `.  I'll bet you did `animalColour = animalColor.add(...);`

Comment: And `animalColour.add(AnimalColour.Brown, AnimalColour.Black)` shoul have given "undefined symbol" or some such error.  `Set`s only have `add` that takes_one_  argument; to add two colors you have to do two `add`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Buzzard` should not be a class in the first place. It should be an instance of `Bird`. The field values you are giving it are too specific for it to be a class (unless there are some parts of `Buzzard` that you did not show here).

You should remove your `Buzzard` class and create an instance of `Bird` called `buzzard` instead:

```
Bird buzzard = new Bird("Buzzard", 
                        "Buteo buteo", 
                        (short) 51, 
                        (short) 57, 
                        550, 
                        1300,
                        EnumSet.of(AnimalColour.BROWN)
                        ... // pass in other parameters
                        );
```

You can also consider using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: One word - `EnumSet`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ah! Forgot that existed. Thanks!

Comment: As in `EnumSet.of(AnimalColour.BROWN)`. You can drop the declaration and do it inline.

Comment: "_Buzzard should not be a class in the first place_" - not too sure on that one. A buzzard is _class_ of bird - an instance is an individual.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Look what the fields the classes have. The classes don't seem to represent any one particular animal. One animal wouldn't have a `minWieght` and a `maxWeight`, or a set of `countries`. The classes here seem to represent pages in some kind of an encyclopaedia. You'd have a page titled "Buzzard", that contains information about which countries buzzards are from, what are the biggest and smallest buzzards' sizes and weights, and what is the scientific name for buzzards.  You would also have a page for "Sparrow" and a page for "Penguin". Each page is represented by an instance.